# What is the relation between the sentences "$f$ achieves its minimum" and "$f$ is bounded from below"?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, maxima-minima

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. I was discussing with a another student of my calculus class about the relation between "$f$ achieves its minimum" and "$f$ is bounded from below".

About me the correct answer is:

"$f$ achieves its minimum" $\implies$ "$f$ is bounded from below" (by definition of boundedness from below), but the converse it is not necessarily true.

Could someone please confirm (or not) this thing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is correct. The (global) minimum is a lower bound by definition, when it exists. For the converse, think for example $\,f(x) = e^x\,$.

Comment: ... or as continuity was not mentioned, even try $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}x&x>0\\-x&x<0\\42&x=0\end{cases}$$